# How can I model a Array with Arrays in preon

Tags: java, preon

I have a problem here with problem I tried several things I just can't get it to init probably.

```
@TypePrefix(value = "4", size = 8)
public class ArrayObject extends SerializedData {

    @BoundBuffer(match = {(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x01})
    private byte[] magic;
    @BoundNumber(byteOrder = ByteOrder.BigEndian, size = "7")
    private byte value;
    @BoundNumber(byteOrder = ByteOrder.BigEndian, size = "1")
    private int signed;

    @BoundList(size = "value", types = {ArrayObject.class, ByteString.class, SingleByteInteger.class, FourByteInteger.class, KeyValueObject.class, VariableLengthFormat.class})
    private SerializedData[] elements;

    public SerializedData[] getElements() {
        return elements;
    }

}
```

My ArrayObject has List of SerializedData which can hold a ArrayObject (circular dependency). I tried using @LazyLoading but this doesn't help.